# How to populate backend select with records from a static database table in Typo3 CMS 6.2

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

-- *Typo3 CMS version 6.2* --

I have some *entities* which have a `country` property.

In the backend, when inserting/editing one of such entities I would like to be able to pick the country from a `select`.

As different entity types all share the same countries I thought it would be appropriate to store the countries in a db table. Then the countries are not going to be modified via the backend, so I don't need an admin interface for them.

Can this be achieved? How?

Up until now this is what I've come up with in my TCA configuration for one of my entities...

```
'country' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:ape/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_building.country',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_countries',
        'size' => 1,
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'eval' => 'required'
    ),
)
```

...and this is the countries table sql...

```
CREATE TABLE tx_myext_countries (
  uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  pid int(11),
  name varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  code varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);
```

...but while not giving any error it displays an empty select in the backend.

What am I missing?

Should I create a model for the countries? Should I treat them as *entities*? Would it be appropriate to configure it as an external data source?

Any help greatly appreciated!

**Update**

This is my attempt at configuring the `tx_myext_countries` table in TCA:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myext_countries'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'Country',
        'label' => 'name',
        'searchFields' => 'name,code,',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Do you have the TCA configured for the country-table? If so, can you show us that configuration?

Comment: @Jost I updated the question with a code sample of what I tried to setup the table in TCA

Comment: You should at least configure the two columns `name` and `code` of the country-table in TCA. The [documentation of the `select` type in the TCA docs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#foreign-table) says: "The item-array will be filled with records from the table defined here. The table must be configured in $TCA.".

Comment: And another thing: columns of type `select` don't have an `eval` option - in your case you should use `'minitems' => 1` instead.